Expectation under convex order by multiplying
I am trying to understand if the following statement is true, or the conditions under it is satisfied. Let $M,N$ and $X>0$ be random variables. If the following inequality holds for any concave non-decreasing function $u$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[u(N)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(M)]
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[u(NX)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(MX)]
\end{equation}
Note that there is no an assumed relation between $N$ and $M$.

what about the relationship between $X$ and $N,M$?

Define $N$ and $M$ as in a similar question asked by you before, so that $E[u(N)] \leq E[u(M)]$ holds for any concave non-decreasing function.
Let $X = N + 2 > 0$, then
\begin{align*}
& E[u(NX)] = E[u(N^2 + 2N)] = E[u(2N + 1)] = \frac{1}{2}u(-1) + \frac{1}{2}u(3), \\
& E[u(MX)] = u(0). 
\end{align*}
Clearly, there are countless concave non-decreasing functions $u$ such that $
u(-1) + u(3) > 2u(0)$ -- perhaps the most trivial one is $u(x) = x$.

Thank you very much again!
